# MediaPlayer gives ProtocolException for playing some videos

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, protocolexception

I'm using `MediaPlayer` and everything is fine but with some videos. The videos which have problem to playing is playing correctly in the native Android player. I'm getting following warning in the logcat for paying those unplayable videos.

> W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 3214428 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException